# What is the definition of a properly-immersed arc?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, definition, geometric-topology

I am going over a paper in which a theorem includes a condition that certain arcs are "properly-immersed geodesic arcs" in a surface $\Sigma$ with nonempty boundary. I have done a search, but I have not been able to find a definition of this term.  I understand the individual parts, but not the whole; I understand that a properly-embedded arc $\alpha : [0,1] \rightarrow \Sigma$  in a surface $\Sigma$, is one whose endpoints are in $\partial \Sigma $. I assume an immersed arc $\alpha$ is one whose image $\alpha ([0,1]) \subset \Sigma$ is an immersed submanifold of $\Sigma$.

Is this all there is to the concept of a properly-immersed arc $\alpha$ , i.e., $\partial \alpha \subset \partial \Sigma$ and the image $\alpha([0,1])$ is an immersed submanifold of $\Sigma$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An map of manifold pairs
$$
f: (N, \partial N)\to (M, \partial M) 
$$
is called **proper** if $f^{-1}(\partial M)=\partial N$. Here I am assuming that $N$ is compact. Now, apply this to maps which are immersions and $N$ which is a closed interval.

Comment: Ah, so $f(N)$ is an arc that is geodesic in $M$ and it is an immersion. But isn't the condition $f^{-1} (\partial M) = \partial N$ stronger than the usual P.E definition that $f(\partial N) \subset (\partial M)$?

Comment: @user204627: There might be different conventions (for both immersions and embeddings) here. The one which I read requires $f^{-1}(\partial M)=\partial N$. I do not know which paper you are reading, but my guess is that they have in mind the definition I gave. What you should do is to go over the proofs and see which properties of the immersion are being used.

Comment: I think the properness is that the interior curve doesn't touch the boundary of $\Sigma$.

Comment: @STUDENT Not quite.